# Probability: Deriving The Moment Generating Function Given the Definition of a Continuous Random Variable

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

Here's a question I'm working on in my textbook.
It says:

> Let $Y$ be a Normally distributed random variable with mean $μ$ and
>   variance $σ^2$ . Derive the moment-generating function of
>   $X = −3Y+4$

Here's what I have: 
$M_x(t) = E[e^{tx}]$ 
$M_x(t) = E[e^{-3ty + 4t}]$ 
$M_x(t) = e^{4t}E[e^{-3ty}]$

I'm not sure how to use what I know about the moment generating function when it comes to the $E[e^{-3ty}]$ part. There's a -3 in the way, and I'm still new with all of this stuff, so any help would greatly be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-3tY}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{(-3t)Y}\right] = M_{Y}(-3t)$$
where $M_{Y}$ is the moment-generating function (MGF) of $Y$.

Do you know the formula for the MGF of a normally-distributed random variable, mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$?

Comment: $e^{4t}e{-3tμ + /frac{(-3t)^2(/sigma)^2}{2}}$
I think this is correct

Comment: I'm actually quite new to Stack Exchange, so I don't know how to properly format my text when commenting. I tried to use LaTeX here, but it didn't turn out right.

Comment: @JohnNumbers Looks good. Please remember to click the checkbox to approve the answer.